# ASP.NET DateTime.Now wrong Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I'm having a strange result when calling DateTime.Now
So, i did the following .apsx and executed on the server.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Globalization.CultureInfo" %>

<%
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData() 
%>

<%= DateTime.UtcNow %>
<br>
<%= DateTime.Now %>
<br>
<%= TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now) %>
<br>
<%= DateTime.Now.IsDaylightSavingTime() %>
<br>
<%= TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName %>
<br>
<%= TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.DaylightName %>
<br>
<%= TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id %>
```

Here is the result:

```
10/01/2018 13:32:58 
10/01/2018 10:32:58 
-02:00:00 
False 
E. South America Standard Time 
E. South America Daylight Time 
E. South America Standard Time
```

Why DateTime.Now returned a -03:00:00 and not a -02:00:00 time?
Why IsDaylightSavingTime returns false, but it should be True?

Comment: I'm going to guess it's to do with daylight savings. I think there is a IsDaylightSavings flag or something on the timezone.currenttimezone object that will tell whether that's the case

Comment: Infact it's a method that you pass the datetime object to

Comment: It sounds unlikely that this is an ASP.NET issue. Can you reproduce it in a small console app? (Aside from anything else, that's easier to work with.)

Comment: My guess is that `TimeZone` is using one version of the Windows time zone database, but `TimeZoneInfo` is using a different version somehow. What does `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` return?

Comment: (I'd definitely avoid using `TimeZone` in general, btw. `TimeZoneInfo` is much better - although I'd personally prefer to use my Noda Time library :)

Comment: As updated, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id returns "E. South America Standard Time", i think it should be "E. South America Daylight Time". But any ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: The DateTime.Now.IsDaylightSavingTime its wrong, checked the  TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, in fact is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try `DateTimeOffset.Now` instead of `DateTime.Now`. It will report the offset from UTC properly (`DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset`).

It is not DST-aware, use `TimeZoneInfo` for that.

You will keep running into gotchas with `DateTime` and anything concerning timezones.